# What do I bring to an accountant if I own a house?

Tags: united-states, taxes, mortgage, real-estate, new-york

I bought a house in Dec. 2014. I wrote checks and paid both School and County taxes on it in 2015. I have the bills for these taxes. Is that enough? I went on the county property tax information website (http://www.madisoncounty.ny.gov/) but none of that looks like an official tax form.

Also, I've just been using my bank's autopay option for the monthly mortgage + interest payments

Is there anything I need to print out before going to my accountant? Such as my bank statements and the tax summary of my house? None of them looks like an official tax document though.

Comment: Why don't you ask your accountant what he/she requires you to bring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bank should have sent you an official tax document with the amount of interest you paid in 2015 listed. You may be able to also download this document from the bank's website. My own form is a third of a page printout out, so you may not think much of it when you first get that document.

If your taxes were paid into escrow and then paid by the bank, the firm will also have those taxes listed on it. From your description it sounds like you paid your taxes directly. In that case your canceled checks / bank statements should suffice.

Comment: The specific form that you get from the bank is Form 1098. If you want to look at a blank to jog your memory of whether you got one, it's here: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1098.pdf  Regarding taxes, you don't need to prove that you paid them to your accountant. If you know the amount, that's probably enough. If you get audited by the IRS, you may need something more substantive, but even to file your taxes you don't need to prove that the amount is correct. (Of course, you should be sure that it is correct to get your tax correct.)